# Laravel weekly group by eloquent collection error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have orders table, and for each user weekly payments table.
I want to show user that he wil take total payment count on depending week. 
I have created the query but on blade side, when i try to access other tables via eloquent it gives does not exits in this collection.

If i dont use group by function it works. But with group by function it doent

```
$earnings = user()->orders()->where('payment_status',0)- 
>where('status',1)->get()->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('W');
    });
```

In blade side my codes like following;

```
@foreach($earnings as $earning)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$earning->user->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$earning->order->commission}}</td>
    <td>{{$earning->user->bank}}</td>
    <td>{{$earning->user->iban}}</td>
    <td>{{$earning->user->phone}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: here is bro,
https://i.hizliresim.com/3O6mgj.png
it shows normally

Answer (score 0):

`get()` should be last:

```
$earnings = user()->orders()
              ->where('payment_status',0)
              ->where('status',1)
              ->groupBy('created_at')
              ->get();
```

How about using `DATE_FORMAT` function:

```
$earnings = user()->orders()
              ->where('payment_status',0)
              ->where('status',1)
              ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%W')"))
              ->get();
```

Comment: ı want to group by weekly
so when i add get() to last it gives 
       stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given error
when collection grouping get() cant be last

Comment: tried gives below error bro;

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'orders.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `orders` where `orders`.`user` = 17 and `orders`.`user` is not null and `payment_status` = 0 and `status` = 1 group by DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%W'))

Comment: What happens if you run: ```$earnings = user()->orders()->where('payment_status',0)->where('status',1)->get();```  ```dd($earnings);```

Comment: if i dont use group by it shows all orders belongs to user one by one. But i want to group them weekly and sum the commission. There was a problem in groupping

Comment: I see, I just wanted to confirm the issue was in the groupBy

Comment: when grouping orders table cant access to users table. Why happens i cant figure out:)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is `orders`, you can do like this:

```
$earnings = user()->orders()->select('orders.*', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%W') as week"))
    ->where('payment_status',0)
    ->where('status',1)
    ->get()->groupBy('week');
```

Comment: tried
Property [user] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Collection `groupBy()` function returns a collection of grouped collections.

```php
$earningGroups = user()->orders()
    ->where('payment_status',0)
    ->where('status',1)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($earning) {
        return Carbon::parse($earning->created_at)->format('W');
    });
```

Now this is a collection of earning groups, not earnings.

```php
@foreach($earningGroups as $earcningGroupName => $earcningGroup)
    // So here you have a group or earnings

    // I don't know why did you want to group.
    // For an example I will print the group name as a table row  here.
    // But do whatever you want.

    <tr>
        <td>{{ $earningGroupName }}</td>
    </tr>

    // So if you want to loop through earnings, you have to loop again.
    @foreach($earningGroup as $earning)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$earning->user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$earning->order->commission}}</td>
            <td>{{$earning->user->bank}}</td>
            <td>{{$earning->user->iban}}</td>
            <td>{{$earning->user->phone}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks for your reply bro. I have an other question. If i want to show payment amount for each user
for example like below data table showing;

user            totalpayment
1                 50

when i try your code it will give all users, all orders details. I wanna show only total amount for each user in single row like merge same user payment amount and sum it